# How do I complete the mission to launch 8 TLAM missiles at Murmansk?

Tags: coldwaters

How do I complete this mission that requires me to fire missiles at Murmansk? When I move in the direction of Murmansk the mission starts.

It's unclear to me where I should send the missiles, and how do I avoid the aircraft and helicopters that come looking for me as soon as I do?

[image]

Comment: Did you close within 180km (100miles) of the target?

Comment: @Hennes I think so, when combat started I did get a message that I was "close to the deployment zone". How can I tell if I'm close enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TLAM missiles you don't target the intended land target. You target the zone in which they go active. From there they will fly to their preprogramed target. On the map you should see a red circle, target this area when you launch the TLAMs.

Also in your first salvo fire off a MOSS after launch to try and draw air surveillance away from your position, giving you more time to reload your next salvo of missiles.